# How to copy datas from one table into another one with all columns but not id in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I use Laravel 6.x and I need to copy datas from one table to another. As usual both of tables has many columns and I'm looking for a solution where I don't depend on column names. In the future maybe columns will be change and I don't want to touch this part of software on every changes.

I want to do something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO product_copys (SELECT * from products);
```

I want to copy all columns **without** the `id` from the `products` table.

I use `Product` and `ProductCopy` models to handle these datas.

Is there any handy solution for this in Laravel, Eloquent?

Comment: I don't know if there's a solution that doesn't involve column names. How can your program or dbms know which columns match and which columns have different names?

Comment: The laravel models contain column names.

Comment: Yeah, but how can your program figure out on its own which column needs to go where? You need to tell it that at some point.

Comment: And can I say `Product::$fillable`? Or second better soultion if I build a custom array on the model with backupable fields, then say `Product::select($backupableFields)`...?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following

In your `App\Product` Model

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $hidden = ['id'];
    //...
}
```

Then in your Controller

```
$copy = Product::all()->toArray();

ProductCopy::insert($copy);
```

> If you need to process a lot (thousands) of Eloquent records, using
>   the chunk command will allow you to do without eating all of your RAM:

```
Product::chunk(200, function($products)
{
    ProductCopy::insert($products->toArray());
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to avoid: list all columns. And this solution result to query instead one

Comment: I see but the `Product::all()->toArray()` result the Laravel read records into the memory. I don't want to read it, I just want to run a single SQL query without any PHP model handling. This read-chunk-insert method waste resources and will takes more times.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to get columns without `id` column (thanks to [Laravel Tricks](https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/get-table-column-names-as-array-from-eloquent-model)). Here is code for the `Product` model:

```php
    /**
     * Get all columns of model
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public static function getTableColumns() {
        $model = new Product();
        return $model->getConnection()
            ->getSchemaBuilder()
            ->getColumnListing($model->getTable());
    }

    /**
     * Return model's columns without given columns
     *
     * @param Array $without_columns
     * @return Array
     */
    public static function withoutColumn(Array $without_columns) {
        return array_diff(self::getTableColumns(), $without_columns);
    }
```

And here you can use it:

```php
$columns = Product::withoutColumn(['id']);
```

Now need only run a raw SQL query in the controller:

```php
    public function backup() {
        $columns = implode(',', Product::withoutColumn(['id']));

        DB::statement('INSERT INTO product_copys ('.$columns.', date_of_backup) (SELECT ' .
            $columns .', NOW() AS date_of_backup FROM products)');

        return Response::HTTP_OK;
    }
```